# How to list subpages on separate menu per page

Tags: routes, navigation, 7

Say I have a structure like this:

```
Mammals
  Rodents
     Mice
     Gerbils
  Felines
     Ocelots
Birds
   Songbirds
   Raptors
       Eagles
Reptiles
    Lizards
```

Etc

I would like for the main menu to display: Mammals, Birds, Reptiles.

But when you are on, for instance, Mammals, or any of it's children. I wish for there to be an additional menu that shows all of the main parent and children (so in this case mammals, rodents, mice, gerbils, felines, ocelots).

Is there any way to set this up or a module that would help? I guess that the first step would be page groups, but I don't see reference to this hierarchy other than creating automatic menus.

(using drupal 7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Menu Block Split](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block_split) module.

> With this module you can split any menu block into two different blocks: a first block with the first level menu entries only and a second block with any second level and sub level menu entries. You can have as many splitted blocks as you need.

There is a Drupal 7 development version, just posted this evening.

Comment: crazy timing! I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that modules such as Nice menus or Superfish Menus do not meet your need, but both of these allow for creation of multi-level menus that show the top level, but expand as you hover over a menu item with children.

Comment: i don't want a dropdown menu.. this set-up is explicitly to avoid that. I need a separate menu. I might be able to hack it with custom css/js on a dropdown menu, though.